# How to detect if cursor is standing still?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know jQuery can handle javascript events onmousemove. But is there any way to use jquery or javascript to detect if a mouse is standing still? In other words, detect if the user has moved their mouse to a given location and then stopped moving it.

Comment: not unless you want to create an interval querying constantly on mousemove.

Comment: Use a timer a counter, and a "onmousemover" event that resets the counter, when the counter reaches a number - declare the pointer as idle.

Comment: Basically you need to log mouse move. Assuming that you are recording each mouse move, 1. check the coordinates when you mouseenter the element. 2. check the coordinates when you mouseleave

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum do I use setInterval for the timer?

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-mint.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
var timer;
var timeout = function () {
    alert('No movement!');
}
timer = setTimeout(timeout, 5000);
window.onmousemove = function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(timeout, 5000);
};
```

Just replace the timeout function with whatever you need and set the desired interval. If you need to check whether the mouse has stopped over some specific element, then change window to some other selector.